# How to set the limit to the parameters in optim function?

Tags: r

Excuse me. In optim function, how can I set the boundary for the `par[1]`, `par[2]`, `par[3]` under MLE?

I have tried the code below, it does not work and my method is not L-BFGS-B either.

get dataset

```r
getSymbols("GOOG", from = "2008-06-30", to = "2018-06-30", src = "yahoo")
```

1. get the GOOG daily return

   ```r
   goog.daily <- abs(df.goog$daily.returns)
   ```
2. take absolute value

   ```r
   goog.daily <- abs(df.goog$daily.returns)
   ```
3. MOGPD Negative Likelihood

   ```r
   neg_lik <- function(par, data, u) {
     xi <- par[1]
     sigma <- par[2]
     delta <- par[3]
     llog <- rep(0, length(data))

     for (i in 1:length(data)) {
       if (data[i] <= u) { llog[i] <- 0 }
       else {
         llog[i] <- -log(delta) + ((1+xi)/xi) * log(1+xi*(data[i] - u)/sigma) + 
               log(sigma) + 2*log(1-(1-delta)*(1+xi*(data[i] - u)/sigma)^(-1/xi))
       }
     }

     return(sum(llog))
   }
   ```
4. estimate parameter MOGPD

   ```r
   optim <- optim(c(0.5, 1, 1), neg_lik, 
                  lower=c(0, 0, 0), upper = c(100, 100, 100), 
                  data = goog.daily, u = thresh)
   ```

Comment: What is *enter code here*?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Sorry, that is my typo

Comment: Then you should edit the question and remove it. Also, you repeat the code of points 1) and 2).

Answer (score 5):

**tl;dr** add `method="L-BFGS-B"`, as follows:

```
opt_res <- optim(c(0.5,1,1),neg_lik,
                 lower=c(0,0,0),
                 upper=c(100,100,100),
                 method="L-BFGS-B",
                 data=goog.daily,u=thresh)
```

(it's not recommended to call your result "optim"; it will generally work but occasionally will cause *lots* of confusion)

---

If you want to impose constraints on the parameters, you have to use `method="L-BFGS-B"`;
the `lower` and `upper` arguments *only* apply in this case. (There are R packages that provide other constrained optimization choices, e.g. `nloptr`.) From `?optim`:

> ... includes **an** option for
> box-constrained optimization ...

("an" in this case meaning "only one"; emphasis added), and

> lower, upper: Bounds on the variables for the ‘"L-BFGS-B"’ method, or
> bounds in which to *search* for method ‘"Brent"’.

(Brent's method is only for single-parameter optimization). This implies (although does not state it explicitly) that these arguments only work for `method="L-BFGS-B"`.

Also, when you run your model with `lower` and/or `upper` set you get a warning:

> Warning message:
> In optim(...) :
> bounds can only be used with method L-BFGS-B (or Brent)

Comment: Thanks, I have checked that warning message in advance. But I do not know how to solve this.

Comment: as my answer says, **you have to use `method="L-BFGS-B"`**